# Formating input and label tags with css vertically

Tags: html, css, input, label

I have this HTML and css code that is a Form...

I tried with another solutions that i found in other questions and i can't align the `input` and the `labels` "vertically"...

Can anyone help me?

**PS.: in my browser (`Firefox`) it looks like in this image...**
[image]

---

```css
<style type="text/css">.modal {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  color: #B1EBF9;
}

.close {
  color: #111;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#divMain,
.post-menu {
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #3B474C;
  float: center;
  /*        border: 1px solid #000;
*/
  width: 35%;
  height: 35%;
  padding: 1%;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-right: 40%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#up input {
  /*background-color: #546E7A;*/
  text-align: center;
  appearance: none;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  min: 0;
}

input {
  background-color: #3B474C;
  color: #B1EBF9;
  border: 2px #28C953 solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

#buttonUpdate {
  background-color: #28C953;
  margin-top: 3%;
  border: 2px #28C953 solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-left: 6%;
  padding-right: 6%;
  color: #3B474C;
  font-weight: bold;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div id="popup" class="modal" onclick="if (event.target == document.getElementById('popup')){window.location = '/dashboard/clientBackup/';}">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <form action="" method="post">
      <div id="up">
        <input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="S90LWPAUTykZXspFHHUQ1JXCBRnzXHK2PfgDvTO2mShTEzxI1csOWLQRQbQQgt5q" type="hidden">
        <p>
          <label for="id_identificador">Identificador:</label>
          <input name="identificador" value="devserver-fd" required="" id="id_identificador" maxlength="200" type="text">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="id_email">Email:</label>
          <input name="email" value="example@example.com" required="" id="id_email" maxlength="200" type="text">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="id_n_jobs">N jobs:</label>
          <input name="n_jobs" value="1" required="" id="id_n_jobs" type="number">
        </p>
      </div>
      <input id="buttonUpdate" value="Update" type="submit"><br>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks vertical in your snippet

Comment: depends in you resolution probably but see in the image... i only want to have it formated vertically and not all centered and not aligned

Comment: Oh yea sorry, wasn't full screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have `<p>` tags as your containers for the input + labels instead of `<div>` but I just used `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` to orient it vertically.

So the last style for `form p` is the only thing I changed.

If you want labels left aligned for example just add:

```
form p label {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```css
<style type="text/css">.modal {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  color: #B1EBF9;
}

.close {
  color: #111;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#divMain,
.post-menu {
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #3B474C;
  float: center;
  /*        border: 1px solid #000;
*/
  width: 35%;
  height: 35%;
  padding: 1%;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-right: 40%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#up input {
  /*background-color: #546E7A;*/
  text-align: center;
  appearance: none;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  min: 0;
}

input {
  background-color: #3B474C;
  color: #B1EBF9;
  border: 2px #28C953 solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

#buttonUpdate {
  background-color: #28C953;
  margin-top: 3%;
  border: 2px #28C953 solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-left: 6%;
  padding-right: 6%;
  color: #3B474C;
  font-weight: bold;
}

form p {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div id="popup" class="modal" onclick="if (event.target == document.getElementById('popup')){window.location = '/dashboard/clientBackup/';}">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <form action="" method="post">
      <div id="up">
        <input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="S90LWPAUTykZXspFHHUQ1JXCBRnzXHK2PfgDvTO2mShTEzxI1csOWLQRQbQQgt5q" type="hidden">
        <p>
          <label for="id_identificador">Identificador:</label>
          <input name="identificador" value="devserver-fd" required="" id="id_identificador" maxlength="200" type="text">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="id_email">Email:</label>
          <input name="email" value="example@example.com" required="" id="id_email" maxlength="200" type="text">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="id_n_jobs">N jobs:</label>
          <input name="n_jobs" value="1" required="" id="id_n_jobs" type="number">
        </p>
      </div>
      <input id="buttonUpdate" value="Update" type="submit"><br>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's because i'm using the update form that `django` provides me using update views ( generic class).

Comment: Now, my form looks like in this print http://i.prntscr.com/NFBu8sVrTiOmsntbjyFgUQ.png :( your code is working but I probably have something messing with it...

Comment: You can add a fixed width to the inputs. Like width: 300px. and then add align-items: center; to the form p

Comment: Worked perfectly!!